# Adding graphic style to text containing image within in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, clipping-mask, graphic-styles

Originally I added a graphic style to text that contained an image within them.
Now, I'm trying to recreate the design and add the same graphic style.

1) I outlined the text, then used compound path and clipping mask to get the image within the text. Seem to work fine.

But when I try to add the graphic style to the text nothing happens.

Also, I cant figure out how to remove the unused portion of the image from the text. Any suggestions?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to recreate. [image: The finished product]

Comment: Do you have an screenshot/example of the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Here is the finished design.

Comment: I think you must make the clip using a copy of the text without the style. Leave your text with style behind it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I clipped the image to the text first. Now I'm trying to add the graphic style to the text.

Answer (score 2):

As [LeoNas](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/102252/leonas) pointed out, having a duplicate layer with the graphic style is the simplest way to achieve this.

Top layer is your image clipped by the text outline 
[image: Top layer is your image clipped by the text outline]

Bottom Layer is your text outline with graphical style applied.
[image: Bottom Layer is your text outline with graphical style applied]

By their powers combined!
[image: clipped text with graphical style]

Comment: OOOOOHHHH!!!!!! I understand now. I'm gonna try it. Thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using Graphic styles is definitely a great idea! It gives you great control and you don't even have to outline your text so you can keep it editable. Stick to that idea!

Create an object. Then use Appearance panel to add strokes, fills and effects...

About the image: no need to use clipping paths (assuming you want a repeatable image). What you could do is to create a new pattern out of it. Choosing a seamless image could be handy here.
Import your image, embed it, open the Pattern options panel and create a new pattern. It is now added to your swatch Panel.  Select your object fill and apply this pattern to it.

Finally, select your object and create your Graphic Style (by dragging into your panel or by clicking "New Graphic style".)

You can now apply this Graphic Style to your text or objects. Cool ^^

More infos about creating a Graphic style can be found here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html
If you experience trouble with the Pattern part, you can read this: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/patterns.html

See the example below (in French but I'm sure you can figure it out):

[image]